# Modelica SemiLinear()

Tags: modelica

Anyone who knows well Modelica Language, specifically thermo-fluid toolbox? Often there is a semiLinear() function, used to calculate the flow of enthalpy, as it depends flow direction.

Anyone who knows the details of this function, if we can remplace it by some simple commands?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Maybe you want to take a look at the [Modelica Web Reference](http://modref.xogeny.com/) which was recently presented by Michael Tiller from Xogeny.

Answer (score 4):

I am pretty sure I already answered this on the OpenModelica forums... Anyway, the [ModelicaReference](https://build.openmodelica.org/Documentation/ModelicaReference.Operators.%27semiLinear%28%29%27.html) package does explain it quite clearly.